# Using the AWS EC2 Query API

Tags: amazon-web-services, api, amazon-ec2

I am currently writing an interface layer to the AWS EC2 Query API, and I was having a relative degree of success until I started digging deeper into its features.

I can run the following query request with no problems:

`?Action=DescribeInstances&DryRun=False&MaxResults=1000&Version=2016-11-15`

However, when I start using Filters on the `DescribeInstances` action, I run into unexplanable errors.

Howver this query, which uses the ip-address filter describe [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/API_DescribeInstances.html):
`?Action=DescribeInstances&DryRun=False&Filter.1.Name=ip%2Daddress&Filter.1.Value=52%2E204%2E71%2E190&MaxResults=1000& Version=2016-11-15`

Thanks in advance!
...will result in the following error:

> AWS was not able to validate the provided access credentials (AuthFailure)

Can someone give me pointers on where I am going wrong?

*UPDATE*: To reiterate, I suspect that this error message is a red herring. I have tried both of the above queries on an EC2 Image with the Administrator IAM role attached, and I still get the same behavior. So unless there is a good reason to suspect a traditional AuthFailure, ask yourselves why an *Adminisrator* can access the DescribeImages action without issue, but causes an AuthFailure when a Filter is added. I hope this is due to my use of said Filters and that its my implementation that is at issue. Thanks.

*UPDATE2*: While a few responses have been helpful, this question still has not yet been answered to my satisfaction.

*UPDATE3*: It looks like Amazon has fixed this issue on its own.

Comment: Any details how exactly are you executing the query?

Comment: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/iam-validate-access-credentials/

Comment: Please provide the detail how you are accessing the API and where. Apparently it is authentication issue. Are you using SDK or using postman or curl?

Comment: @Xliff Is there a reason you are writing your own queries instead of using an AWS SDK from your programming language? An SDK will take care of all authentication for you. If you write your own HTTPS queries, you'll need to add authentication information yourself.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein, the AWS SDK is *not* available in my language

Comment: @mon - If it is an authentication issue, then why does DescribeInsances work without parameters, as do most other actions? It's just applying filters that seems to be the issue. Do filters require separate access items via IAM?

Comment: @Marcin, I am using the query API via a module provided by my language of choice (Raku). Can I ask what further details you require?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein - Further more, I have written my own authentication routines in said language, and they work for a decent number of actions like RunInstances, StopInstance and StartInstance. If my authentication routines were wrong, I would expect to see more errors of this sort in my code. What would you suspect may be wrong given this further bit of info? Thanks.

Comment: @mon - Then why does the endpoint work *at all*? Sometimes error messages can be misleading. I suspect this is one of those times.

Comment: "AWS was not able to validate the provided access credentials (AuthFailure)" is as clear as it can get. How about ssh into an EC2 instance with Admiistrator IAM role attached as its profile and run the query? If it works, then for sure it is auth issue.

Comment: @Xliff, I suppose it is great to get to the bottom of why or mechanism but we will not able to see the implementation code of AWS services (and possibly not worth spending so much effort to do so). Software has issues, so why not found a solution/workaround and move on?

Comment: @mon - That's what I am attempting. If we have reached the limits of your knowledge, then I thank you for your help.

Comment: @mon - I just noticed your suggestion about attaching the IAM role to an instance, and that seems like a good next step. Thanks!

Comment: Your query is correct. It works as intended. I just checked it using postman. So back to the first question. How are you executing this query? Have you written entire code to generate aws signature yourself?

Comment: @Marcin - Yes. I wrote the entirety of the query code. Did you verify both versions of my query? If so, then I guess I will need to go to one of t0he official language bindings and port their code. Thanks for the observation!

Answer (score 2):

In your URL-encoded request, there seems to be a space in `'& Version...'`.

Back to the larger picture, perhaps you should consider running [awscli](https://aws.amazon.com/cli/) from your code (in a subprocess), rather than trying to make your own requests and sign them yourself?

Also, awscli itself is really quite handy (and complete).  For starters, it helps formulate the request and quickly see what gets returned.

Also, you can use it with `--debug` to observe (among other things) the request and the response sent over the wire.

Example:

```sh
aws ec2 describe-instances --region us-east-1 \
  --filters "Name=ip-address,Values=${IP}" \
            "Name=instance-state-name,Values=running" \
  --max-items 10 \
  --query 'Reservations[*].Instances[*].PrivateIpAddress' \
  --output json \
  --debug
```

Output:

```
2020-12-27 xx:xx:xx,xxx - MainThread - botocore.endpoint - DEBUG - Making request for OperationModel(name=DescribeInstances) with params:
  {'body': {u'Filter.1.Name': u'ip-address', u'Filter.2.Value.1': u'running',
  u'Filter.2.Name': u'instance-state-name', 'Version': u'2016-11-15',
  'Action': u'DescribeInstances', u'Filter.1.Value.1': u'xx.xxx.xxx.xxx'},
  'url': u'https://ec2.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/', 'headers': {'Content-Type':
  'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8',
  (...), 'method': u'POST'}
```

Comment: Thank you for noticing that! I will attempt to rectify that. With respect to using `awscli` -- while a valld workaround that is not the design goal of this code. I need to use the query API because I want XML output, not JSON.

Comment: At the very least, you can use it to explore the capabilities and debug. Both `awscli` and `boto3` are usually some of the first SDKs to get support for new AWS features. There is a fair amount that is generated programmatically from the API specs, so you know it it's a reference implementation. Also, it's open source and you can easily inspect the code, run the tests, run in debugger to see exactly what's going on, etc. It's really quite wonderful.

Comment: Also, while I understand the desire to provide a more native SDK for your language, it's still going to be a game of whack-a-mole to keep up with all the new features. Overall, I would think it to be 100x easier to translate JSON to XML and then call it a day.